# loop through array and create new array python

Tags: python

I have a array, let's say:

```
preco = array([5,4,4,5)
```

I would like to loop through my array and create a new array like this:

lebo

```
[array([5]),array([5,4]),array([5,4,4]),array([5,4,4,5)]
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: is that a numpy array?

Answer (score 2):

You can use list `slicing` within a list comprehension :

```
>>> l=[5,4,4,5]
>>> [l[:i] for i in range(1,len(l)+1)]
[[5], [5, 4], [5, 4, 4], [5, 4, 4, 5]]
```